# Can't find weston.ini on Ubuntu 17.10 to turn on Numlock

Tags: xorg, wayland, numlock, weston

From my basic understanding Ubuntu 17.10 now uses Wayland instead of Xorg, even though it is still possible to switch between the two.

I want to have my numlock key ON when I enter Ubuntu. I read people usually install numlockx to enable it, but it seems that it only works on Xorg.

I also read that in the Weston implementation of Wayland there is a config file where I can turn on the numlock key by defaul. Documentation [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man5/weston.ini.5.html).

But I can't seem to find this weston.ini config file on my Ubuntu 17.10. Does ubuntu not use Weston? Is there a way for me to achieve this numlock behavior without having to switch GDM to Xorg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu does use Wayland as the default (on GPUs which it can work on). However, Wayland is simply a protocol definition. Weston is one implementation of the protocol, but it is not the implementation used by default in Ubuntu. The implementation used in Ubuntu, is the GNOME shell itself.

Comment: So are you saying to find something in Gnome Shell to control num lock behavior?

Comment: there should be a setting for numlock in gnome settings somewhere

Answer (score 0):

add

```
[keyboard]
numlock-on=true
```

to `~/.config/weston.ini`

Weston is the reference implementation of a Wayland compositor

you can start it with `weston` from a `tty` [ctrl alt backspace to exit]