# How do I turn Numlock ON for login screen Ubuntu 17.10 Wayland

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, wayland, numlock

I know this question comes up a lot, and I've seen some answers.

But the thing is, from what I understand numlockx is made for Xorg and does not work on Wayland.

I saw that some implementations of Wayland like Weston have a config file where I can chose the default behavior for numlock. But I haven't been able to find anything similar for the Gnome Shell implementation on Ubuntu 17.10

Also, I have numlock ON on my UEFI, and it is on during GRUB, but after I start Ubuntu it is switched off.

How can I manage to set this behavior without having to change to Xorg?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/977793/692175

Comment: That question was also made by me and does not solve the problem. Just made me understand unlockx wont work on Wayland.

Comment: The point was to remind you that there's no point in bringing up weston again. I hope you get an answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set it as *gdm* user via gsettings command

The solution that should work:

1. Open terminal via Ctrl+Alt+T, then run command to get root privilege:

   > sudo -i
2. Switch to user *gdm* in the terminal:

   > su gdm -s /bin/bash
3. Finally set ‘Numlock on’ via *gdm* user:

   > gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'

Restart the computer and done

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the reputation to comment so I have to post this this way.

The @bonhomag 's solution does not work for me. The procedure works with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state on
```

instead of the last command in his answer (same command but no `''` around the `on`).

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Found that on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Tips_and_tricks).