# How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, numlock

I have a fresh 18.04 install and would like to enable the numlock key for login, without switching to the older lightDM. I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028428/how-to-set-numlock-on-as-default-at-login-screen), but when trying the gdm approach I get: `Command 'gdm' not found`
but as said above I would like to achieve this small task, without having to switch to lightDM or do some other major changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:gdm

sudo su gdm -s /bin/bash
```

Now, you need to use `gsettings` or `dconf #or dconf-edit if you have it`

Go to `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/keyboard/numlock-state` and change it to `on`

or simply after the two lines do this

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/keyboard/numlock-state "'on'"
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
```

Now reboot

Comment: Awesome it worked, could you maybe add a bit of explanation what the first command does? The other ones are self explanatory. Looking at the man page of xhost it looks like it adds gdm to the allowed display managers?