# I need to enable numlock on the console /dev/tty{1..6} but there is no /etc/rc.local file on ubuntu focal, what is the canonical way to do that?

Tags: 20.04, tty, numlock

I need to enable numlock on the console `/dev/tty{1..6}` with `setleds` (`numlockx` for is dedicated to X11) :

```bash
#!/bin/sh -e

# Turn Numlock on for the TTYs:
for tty in /dev/tty[1-6]; do
    /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < $tty
done
```

But there is no `/etc/rc.local` file on my system, what is the canonical way to do that ?

Comment: (which in turn links to https://askubuntu.com/questions/886620/how-can-i-execute-command-on-startup-rc-local-alternative-on-ubuntu-16-10)

Comment: @muru I want to lock the numeric keypad in the console ttys not in X11/Xorg. The `numlockx` tool you propose in your [first link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028428/how-to-set-numlock-on-as-default-at-login-screen) is for X11 : `man numlockx | grep X11` prints `       numlockx is a program to control the NumLock key inside X11 session scripts.`

Comment: Good, so you can followe the second paragraph which goes "The problem is, there is no rc.local to start it anymore. You will need to configure systemd to run numlockx once after startup like rc.local would have done. ..." and then links to the second question I commented above.

Comment: @muru Your [second link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886620) contains the solution in the [first answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919598/426176), that is to sum things up : `sudo touch /etc/rc.local`, add the commands, and finally `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local` , thanks.

Comment: @mchid Yes it does. muru already gave it in his second link.